# just administer add to view

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a content type and slider view block to it and I want just when add this content by administer  show in slider and  when another user add this content do not show this content in slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same view create a new block and change its display to appear like you want and make some access control on it;
The first block ( in the same view ) only admin can see it and the second block grant access to normal user .
In the block region make one over the other .
Good luck